# When offline getting error Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(…)(anonymous > function)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following javascript (It toggles visibility of my menu)

```
   <!-- toggle visibility for filter -->
     <script type="text/javascript">
                  $(document).ready(function() {
                      $("#extra-content").hide();
                      $("#toggle-content").click(function(){
                          $("#extra-content").toggle();
                      });
                  });
     </script>
```

but when I am offline (I programme during my commute) I am getting error from this script

> (index):101 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(…)(anonymous
>   function) @ (index):101

How I can figure out what js file to copy locally to make it work offline?

UPDATE 
This is how I load jquery

```
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/static/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/static/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: The jQuery file

Comment: if you include jQuery through a cdn, this requires internet access because it downloads it from a cdn. you should download jquery instead.

Comment: check with jquery link

Answer (score 2):

You will also have an additional error in the console that indicates a `404 not found`.

This is the file that you need to copy locally.

Looking at the error this is almost certainly jQuery.

Comment: +1 - Only one who adressed his question *How I can figure out what js file to copy locally to make it work offline?*

Answer (score 1):

How Jquery is loaded ? If you get it by the cdn it's normal than you can't access it when offline.
Try to donwload it and install it locally

Comment: So, as you're offline I guess it's `{{ STATIC_URL }}/static/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js` who should be loaded ? Is it a local url right ? As Graham Ritchie wrote above, you can see the error in the console and find the 404 error. So you'll know which file are not loaded and where your browser look for them.

Answer (score 1):

$ is not defined error is thrown when **jquery** file is not loaded.
Since you are using jQuery `"$(document).ready(function(){});"`, you must ensure that jquery is loaded, either you copy jquery.min.js file locally or you can use HTML **Application Cache** feature as you are working offline. This will store your jquery.min.js file and will available untill you clear the cache.